# git how to just git and not track

Tags: git

My environment is like this: A dev computer that makes changes to the repository and publishes the repo after commits.

Test box: where the repo is cloned. When running dotnet build it creates files that get attached to the repo. Don't wan this test box to track files and just want to run git pull to get changes without it accounting for the compiled dll's that is created when the project is run.

besides git reset --hard which sometimes fails because of locked files. Just want git to fetch the files from origin and overwrite if necessary files which it feels like tracking.

Comment: If you only need the code and not the versions, branches etc, you can `clone` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a number of solutions here but the one that sticks out the most to me is that you shouldn't be tracking folders that produce builds and other build artifacts. I suggest you add an appropriate `.gitignore` file to stop git from caring about build artifacts.

[Here is an example](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) `.gitignore` file for most common .NET projects.

Answer (score 1):

You might try putting the names of the files you don't want tracked in the .gitignore file on the test box.
.gitignore lives in the directory at the top of your source, (where the .git dir lives).

Here are a few examples of files often put in the .gitignore file:

`*.hex
*.bin
*.cyacd
*.rgn
*.dlx`

Comment: ok what worked was to add .gitignore from the solution folder and add /src/projectname/bin  /obj and /logs